# DirectX 9, 10, 11 Code differences for learning

Tags: c++, graphics, directx

I want to start learning DirectX and I do have an extremely strong grasp of C++

Anyways I have searched online and I saw that people recommend that I start with dx9 then move my way up to the other DXs

Now my question is

If I learn dx9 and fully grasp it then move on to Dx10 and then to Dx11 Will that cause me to get mixed up while I'm programming when I learn the newer DirectX because of the similar code 
or will it help me understand the language and be better at using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, there's not an awful lot of point in learning DX10. If you don't need hardware compatibility, go straight to DX11. If you do, then stick with DX9. The hard part about graphics programming has little to do with the API- most of it is in programmable shaders and techniques that are not strongly tied to the API you're using.

Comment: So you mean that I basically should leave Dx9 and Dx10 and go ahead and learn Dx11 straight away, correct?  (If I don't care about hardware compatibility)

Comment: Go with DX11, look into feature levels, you can still target DX9 and DX10 level hardware with the DX11 API.

Comment: @Mohamed: Yes. There is no value in knowning the older API.

Comment: I have windows xp, so will that be a problem when Im trying to program in DirectX11

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil It is always going to be more difficult to develop on a machine which cannot test your code, than on one which can.

Comment: Basically if i program anything in 11  All xp users wont be able to use it